# How to Clean URL using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am very frustrated looking for working clean URL using `.htaccess`:

My `.htaccess` code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ $1.php  [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)$ product.php?id=$1
```

The first rule is percfectly working in hiding the .php extension of my URL but the second rule is not working. The URL of my product after clicking the product ID no on the product list. I'm using free host for now. **freehost.16mb.com/product?id=156**

My Code of my product list link is:

```
<a href="product.php?id=<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>"> link 1 array </a>
```

So I'll try to clean the URL using `.htaccess` into **freehost.16mb.com/product/156**.

I am using the `.htaccess` code above but it doesn't work for me. I need some help.

Answer (score 0):

Your second rule does not make the provision for the leading `/product` before the ID, and your HTML anchor is using the format that you are rewriting to - this needs to be swapped around.

Change your anchor tag to the following:

```php
<a href="/<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>
```

You also need to fix your rule up a bit by adding the `QSA` and `L` flags, and by removing the leading slash from the rule's pattern:

```bash
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ product.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Once you've done that, `/1234` will rewrite to `/product.php?id=1234`.

However, if you wish for the `/product` segment to be included, then use these instead:

```php
<a href="/product/<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>
```

```bash
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9]+)$ product.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: if i change <a href="/product/<?php echo $row['ID']; ?> this link from list_items.php and it will redirect to product.php there is $_GET['id']. The GET['id'] will be undifined.

Comment: In `product.php`, what happens when you put `var_dump($_GET); die()` at the top of the file?

Answer (score 0):

Just Use this in your .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule product/id/(.*)/ product?id=$1
RewriteRule product/id/(.*) product?id=$1
```

This will turn your URL into:

freehost.16mb.com/product/id/156

To have freehost.16mb.com/product/156 just remove the id/ from the RewriteRule, so it will be:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule product/(.*)/ product?id=$1
RewriteRule product/(.*) product?id=$1
```

---- ALTERNATIVE ----

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=156($|&)
RewriteRule ^freehost\.16mb\.com/product$ /freehost.16mb.com/product/156?&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Comment: Hey @Acy, see my question for an alternative method I've just added. However, it is more specific to that ID.